# Can I work in US as well as India when on F-1 visa

Tags: f1-student-visa

As a student on the F-1 visa, Am I allowed to work online with income coming to my bank account in my home country. Will that be a violation any F-1 rules?

Comment: This is more of an immigration question than a finance question.

Answer (score 2):

An F-1 student can work in a few circumstances:

- Working on campus
- Working on CPT
- Working on OPT once you get an EAD
- Working on an EAD obtained for economic hardship

Remote online work wouldn't be work on campus. Unless you get your school to approve it as part of CPT (I don't even know if they can approve CPT for foreign online work), it is not CPT. If you have an EAD for OPT, and the remote work is in your field of study, you can do it. If you have an EAD for economic hardship, you can do the remote work regardless of field. Otherwise, it would be in violation of F-1 status.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I have a follow-up question. Can my income in the home country be tracked back in the US if I don't show this income in US and pay taxes for it in my home country.